# NewForm.aspx slides in from any page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, newform

In modern experience List, when you click NEW - the form slides in from the right.  Is there a way to do the same through a link?

For example, when user clicks the link to `newform.aspx` located anywhere else (except the actual list), I need the form to slide in from the right.

I found similar questions from years ago but no answers. I'm hoping there are new developments since.

I tried below but its opening a classic modal. I'd like it to open the form edited in PowerApps.

```
function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Title of the Dialog',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 500,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
}
```